# App Engine dispatch.yaml to external server

Tags: google-compute-engine, google-app-engine

I have a VueJS site on app engine, I would like to use wordpress for a blog placing it on the same domain at the same level at the /blog/ directory.

I can probably do this with dispatch.yaml and having wordpress hosted on the same GAE project as an additional service but then i need to purchase Google Cloud SQL which is overpriced for my use case, Id rather use a compute instance with php and sql running.

Is there any way to achieve this ? using App Engine or does it all have to be moved to a compute instance ?

Comment: Google Cloud SQL is a bargain for companies when you factor features, managed services and employee salaries. For self hosting, Compute Engine is a good/smart choice for running your own website + MySQL/MariaDB.

Comment: Its expensive when your website is not generating any revenue

Answer (score 1):

Posting this for visibility of others.

As for @John Hanley said:

```
Google Cloud SQL is a bargain for companies when you factor features, managed services and employee salaries. 
For self hosting, Compute Engine is a good/smart choice for running your own website + MySQL/MariaDB.
```

Additional Reference:

- [Google Cloud Engine](https://cloud.google.com/compute/all-pricing)
- [Cloud SQL pricing](https://cloud.google.com/sql/pricing)

Comment: And as I said it doesnt make it a viable option if you are not a commercial business, its crazy money for a static blog